# Revenue Discrepancies Between Adjust and Firebase

Tags: firebase, adjust-android

I am experiencing huge revenue discrepancies between my firebase and adjust accounts. There is like a 50% difference between platforms. Why do you think that is? What might be the possible reason behind this discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to contact the relevant support, there may be a calculation fault or simply a delay in the results you are seeing. Answering this would require account access to resolve.